# Why is Ein Kelokeinu not said on Yom Kippur?

Tags: tefilla, yom-kippur, musaf

Ein Kelokeinu isn't in my Yom Kippur Machzor, and as far as I can recall, it is not said in Shul after Musaf [or any time, for that matter]. Why is this so?

Comment: In the Chabad machzor it's in Neilah

Comment: What [tom smith](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/732) said; also, some _Ashk'nazi_ congregations say it at the end of _musaf_. However, +1 for the question: in my (limited) experience and according to the ArtScroll _nusach S'farad machzor_ most _nusach S'farad_ congregations do not say it.

Comment: Rinat Yisrael (which is considered authoritative in many regions) does have it, both in nusach Ashkenaz and Sfarad (don't know about Edot Mizrach)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Mishna B'rura](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=163&hilite=)* 622:5 (in my own free translation) explains the *Rama*'s ruling that it's not said with the following explanation:

> That's because on *Shabas* it's said to complete the discrepancy of 100 *b'rachos*, which is not necessary on *Yom Kipur* due to the plethora of praises we say. The make-up of the *k'tores* also needn't be said, as it's included in the *avoda* in *musaf*. But it seems it's better to say it in private so as to enumerate the spices, which are not mentioned in the *avoda* (*Taz*), and the *Magen Avraham* also says to say it.

Comment: Interesting that, because others say we are especially short of the 100 brochos on Yom Kippur when we don't have any food brochos; that's [one of the reasons](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34913&pgnum=250) for smelling spices on YK

Comment: @Michoel, "_En Kelokenu_" only helps meet the _b'racha_ minimum to the extent it's _b'rachos_, which is a very weak sense of "_b'racha_" also met by other things we say on _Y"K_; smelling things to meet the minimum is to meet a stricter sense of "_b'racha_". (_Kach nir'e li_.)

Comment: Interesting idea then, that we fulfill 100 brochos on two different levels; on the one hand Y"K is short, on the other we got extra..

Comment: from https://www.beureihatefila.com/files/2008-09-19_Tefila_Newsletter.pdf quoting the Maharil " In addition, Ain Kelokeinu was composed to commemorate the sacrifices but on Yom Kippur we already mention the many sacrifices of Yom Kippur during our prayers."